# Adding views at runtime or something else

Tags: android, android-layout, android-runtime

My application has a form to fill data (invoice). And just as there is a button to add a new line in the invoice.
So far I use to add new view of the layout, but it is not a suitable option, because, let us assume that the user will need to enter 100 items, which will lead to higher costs and memory performance.
Maybe someone will offer a better option ??

Comment: RecyclerView / ListView

Comment: Thanks, but how can I implement AutoCompleteTextView into RecyclerView's item??

Answer (score 0):

You should use [listview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Each time ths user is adding a new row you can call notifyDataSetChanged() method, this will refresh adapter and add new rows. Each rows is only created when it is shown, so memory consumption stay low.

**Edit**

With listview you should read documentation on [adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) which give you control on elements in your listview.

Comment: sorry, I can`t upload screenshot my form yet (low reputation)